# Obtener instrucciones css desde php

Tags: php, css, cakephp, phpexcel

miren es que en una BD estan ya configuradas las clases que se usan para darle estilo a unos nav un color. Bueno pero les voy a mostar todo por fotos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En esa imagen se ven los nombres de las clases dependiendo de que barra de navegación sea. y se le aplican los siguientes css:

```
.blue-seadog {
    background-color: #00AEEF;
}

.teal {
    background-color: #009688 !important;
}

.amber.darken-1 {
    background-color: #ffb300 !important;
}

.green {
    background-color: #4CAF50 !important;
}

.red {
    background-color: #F44336 !important;
}
```

Y todo hasta ahí muy bien, lo que yo necesito es lo siguiente: obtener esos códigos de colores desde un controlador cakephp, ya que los necesito para lo siguiente:

```
$worksheet->getStyle('H'.$i)->getFill()->setFillType(\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Fill::FILL_SOLID)->getStartColor()->setARGB('FFFF0000');
```

En esa linea le doy un color a una celda de excel, y dependiendo de si la data es de cierto estado debe tener el mismo color de la barra de navegación de ese estado.

Por ejemplo cuando estamos en la vista de activos entonces la barra de navegación es verde, y en el excel los usuario activos deben estar en color verde.

Answer (score 0):

```
{
    "require": {
        "sabberworm/php-css-parser": "*"
    }
}
```

Eso en el composer.json

luego abres la terminal y le das composer update y listo, ya vuelves al proyecto

en el controller haces esto:

```
use Sabberworm\CSS\Parser;
use Sabberworm\CSS\OutputFormat;
```

creas una función si deseas

```
 public function crearClaveValor($arreglo)
        {
            $estilos[]="";
            foreach ($arreglo as $valor) {
                $pos = (strpos($valor, "{"));
                $clases = substr($valor, 0, $pos);
                $clases = trim($clases);
                $valor = str_replace("{", "", $valor);
                $estilos[$clases] = str_replace($clases, "", $valor);
            }
            return $estilos;
        }
```

Guardas en un arreglo los estilos

```
 $oCssParser = new Parser(file_get_contents(WWW_ROOT . 'css' . DS . 'mdb.css'));
        $oCssDocument = $oCssParser->parse();
        $estilos = explode("}", $oCssDocument->render(OutputFormat::createPretty()));
        $estilos = $this->crearClaveValor($estilos);
```

Si imprimes `$estilos` con `pr($estilos);` lo verías así:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y ahora solo debes buscar los colores así:

```
$color = ".".$estado->color; //aquí obtienes la clase
                $matches = []; 
                preg_match ('/#[0-9|A|a|B|b|C|c|D|d|E|e|F|f]+/' , $estilos[$color], $matches); //buscar el color
                $color = ($matches[0]); //guardas el color
                $color = str_replace("#", "", $color);
                $worksheet->getStyle('H'.$i)->getFill()->setFillType(\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Fill::FILL_SOLID)->getStartColor()->setARGB($color);
```

y como prueba aquí les muestro como se vería 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

con ayuda de @KacosPro